# Bad operand type for unary string -:str while drawing a picture

Tags: python, python-3.x, drawing, operand

I am trying to draw a picture for a homework in my computer science class.

```
#==================================
#Program Purpose: Drawing
#
# @Author: Morgan White
# @Version: January 26th, 2013
#==================================
print(                          -----         "Fancy Adventurer")
print(                         "l   l"            "-Morgan White")
print(                         "l   l")
print(                       "---------")
print("                         /   \ ")
print("                        / 0 0 \ ")
print("                       |   .   | ")
print("                        \  -  / ")
print("                         \---/ ")
print("                           | ")
print("                        ^^ | ^^ ")
print("                      /=========\ ")
print("                     /     |     \ ")
print("                    /      |      \ ")
print("                   /       |     |------| ")
print("               |  /        |     |      | ")
print("     <========]|={:}=      |     |      | ")          
print("               |          / \    |------| ")
print("                         /   \ ")
print("                        /     \ ")
print("                       /       \ ")
print("                      /         \ ")
```

I have an error saying

> bad operand type for unary string -:str

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: Python 3.3. I'm not really sure if thats answering you question.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please provide the appropriate tags in your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
print("                          -----         \"Fancy Adventurer\"")
print("                          -----         \"Fancy Adventurer\"")
print("                         l   l            \"-Morgan White\"")
print("                         l   l")
print("                       ---------")
```

You should pass a string to `print` and you do that by putting doublequotes `"` around what you want to print. And if you want to add doublequotes inside the string you will have to escape it with a `\` e.g. like this: `\"`. Furthermore if you want to add `\` to the string you will have to escape `\` with `\` e.g. like `\\`

To avoid the escape add an `r` before the starting double-quote like `r"`.

Hence this would work:

```
print("                          -----         \"Fancy Adventurer\"")
print("                         \"l   l\"            \"-Morgan White\"")
print("                         \"l   l\"")
print("                       \"---------\"")
print(r"                         /   \ ")
print(r"                        / 0 0 \ ")
print(r"                       |   .   | ")
print(r"                        \  -  / ")
print(r"                         \---/ ")
print(r"                           | ")
print(r"                        ^^ | ^^ ")
print(r"                      /=========\ ")
print(r"                     /     |     \ ")
print(r"                    /      |      \ ")
print(r"                   /       |     |------| ")
print(r"               |  /        |     |      | ")
print(r"     <========]|={:}=      |     |      | ")          
print(r"               |          / \    |------| ")
print(r"                         /   \ ")
print(r"                        /     \ ")
print(r"                       /       \ ")
print(r"                      /         \ ")
```

Comment: I am now getting an unexpected character after line continuation character. Its showing up after the \"-Morgan White\"")

Comment: I tried editing it to how you drew it out and i'm getting the same error after the same string.

Comment: Nevermind, I missed a quotation but thank you so much! Is there a way I can give you points or something for answering this?

Comment: Missed it in the copying or is it missed out in this answer?

Comment: @user3238097 Accepting the answer (click on that tick by the down arrow to the left of this answer) and upvoting (up arrow), provided you found the answer helpful/useful.